# Odoo sorting group by month

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

In the Account module, there is a group by filter by default. The group by Invoice month filter.
When it is used, the invoices are grouped by month.[Ascending Invoices month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhlsr.png)

The group is sorted in ascending order. Is there any way to sort it by descending order?

Comment: Why did you add so many Odoo version in the tags? If you think all Odoo versions are related to this question, just use the tag "odoo" alone. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `order_by` with the `invoice_date` field to do the same.